# Objective C beginner - method calls without casting

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective C and there's something odd that I don't understand.

How can I even call a `NSString` method on a `NSDate` object? For example:

```
NSString* ptr = [[NSString alloc] init];
[ptr uppercaseString];
NSDate* dPtr = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[dPtr uppercaseString];
id temp;
[temp uppercaseString];
```

Well, I do get that id can point to anything but how does it even know of the existence of the `uppercaseString` method without casting or something?

I'm have a C++ and Java background where I didn't notice anything like this before.

I'd love to get an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C  methods are not the same as Java or C++ methods.  They are messages, and they exist independently of any class or object.  When you write (taken from [CocoaDevCentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)) in Photo.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Photo : NSObject {
    NSString* caption;
    NSString* photographer;
}

- caption;
- photographer;

@end
```

you are saying that the `Photo` class has a caption and a photographer object, and that it will respond to the messages `caption` and `photographer`.  That was the old pre-properties way of writing code for those two items.

You will write code in `Photo.m` giving the implementation of the two messages, so that a `Photo` can respond to them.  But nothing stops you from sending `caption` to any object.  It's like the old Far Side cartoon about what we say to dogs and what they hear. Any errors occur at runtime.

So, what happens when you send a message to an object that it does not know how to respond to?  If you have not done anything special,

1. The runtime system packages the message into a thing of type `SEL`.
2. It sends the `doesNotRecognizeSelector:` message to the object with that selector.
3. The object inherits from `NSObject` an implementation that raises a `NSInvalidArgumentException`.

However, there are a few opportunities before that to intervene by overriding a method:

- `+ (BOOL) resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL`

This lets you install an implementation at runtime.

- `- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector`

This lets you nominate another object to accept the message.

- `- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation`

This lets you handle the message any way you want.

Before Objective-C gained blocks, there were a number of libraries that used forwarding for functional programming.  Suppose you have an `NSArray` of `Account`s that all understand the `balance` message.  Suppose then you want to collect the balances of all the accounts in another `NSArray`. Instead of looping, the library provided a *category* for `NSArray` with a `collect` message, and you would write:

```
NSArray *accounts = ...;
NSArray *balances = [[accounts collect] balance];
```

The result of `[accounts collect]` does not have an implementation for the `balance` message; how could it?  `collect` is provided by the library.  Instead, it has a `forwardInvocation:` implementation that sends the `balance` message to all the members of `accounts`, and creates a new `NSArray` from them.  One might use blocks and `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` these days, but that was a quite succinct and powerful technique.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Java and C++, Objective-C has weak typing and *late binding*, which explains that you don't have to do a cast.

This is one of big dividing lines in object-oriented programming: Whether the language uses strong typing, so a variable can only hold references (or pointers) to objects of a given class and its subclasses, or if it can hold anything. If a variable can hold any object, the exact method implementation then has to be resolved at runtime when a message is received.

Objective-C got the philosophy of late binding from Smalltalk (see [smalltalk](/questions/tagged/smalltalk)), but is moving towards a more and more strictly typed language (formal protocols, use of the `id` type discouraged, etc.).  The basics remain the same, however.

This is also one of the reasons, contrary to C++, Objective-C needs a runtime in order to run on your machine. Something has to take care of those method lookups.

Comment: The other languages have late binding too. They only cast because they want to do more syntactic checks (mainly hold for java, but c++ got late binding too)

Comment: @Daij-Djan - Java/C++ have *dynamic dispatch*, which is essentially indexed lookup into a known method table (multiple inheritance in C++ makes it a bit more complicated). Objective-C has late binding, which is essentially a search in an unknown method table. Casting is needed for more than syntactic checks, in some cases it is required to be able to compile the call at all. Java/C++ really don't have the equivalent of `id` due to this difference.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java ... I can agree we are both partly right ;) I didn't know about dynamic dispatch and called it late binding but it still has it in other ways

Comment: But what I also mentioned in my answer is that the method call is actually not happening here - and that is the real reason it works like it does.)

Answer (score 2):

Because the check for the existence of the method is not made right before the call but while trying to find the method. What actually happens (simplified a lot is)

`[obj methodCall];`

=> replaced => `objc_send(obj, @"methodCall")`

Inside the C function objc_send The call itself is resolved and made

`If(obj.respondsTo(methodCall) Then obj.methodCall();`

Comment: the `objc_msgSend` function takes a **selector** as its 2nd argument. Furthermore, it doesn't check for the method being existent - it calls it whether or not an object responds to the message sent.

Comment: @H2CO3 What about GREATLY simplified was unclear .. I know it takes a selector but does that benefit the OP in any way? Also I am aware it calls responds ;) I have used that also -- Ill rename it

Comment: @H2CO3 - I think you'll find it is `objc_msgSend` which does the check for existence - it can't just call the method without a code address to go to! If it finds no implementation of the method it then invokes the Obj-C process that @EricJablow has described.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided the answer - late binding, the method is looked up on the object at runtime without concern for the type of the object - if it has an appropriate method it is called.

However your call above `[dPtr uppercaseString]` should produce an error from Xcode. While the compiler will perform a lot of checks and refuse to compiler some programs (such as the above) that is really all the type-checking you get and it can be easily by-passed (e.g. `[(id)dPtr uppercaseString]` will remove the error and let you code run - when it will promptly fault due to no such method on `NSDate`).

Essentially the types are comments, if you use them properly you code should be type-correct, but there is no requirement for type-correctness for your code to compile.